# A statement w.r.t. the injection of $\mathbb{Z^+}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $v$ be an injection form $\mathbb{Z^+}$ to $\mathbb{Z^+}$ without any fixed points. Denote the image of $v$ as $v\left(\mathbb{Z^+}\right)$. Take a subset $S \in v\left(\mathbb{Z^+}\right)$ s.t. $S$ and $v\left(\mathbb{Z^+}\right) \setminus S$ are both countably infinite. Is $\left(\mathbb{Z^+}\setminus S\right)\cap \left(\mathbb{Z^+}\setminus v^{-1}\left(S\right)\right)$ also countably infinite?

Also I am not sure if "$v$ does not have fixed points" helps to prove or disprove this statement.

Comment: Do you mean finite rather than countable?  otherwise this is a triviality.

Comment: it is countable. i just cannot see the fact instantly. could you explain more?

Comment: Are you using "countable" to mean "countably infinite"? (If so, the body of your question should be edited to make this clear. It is perhaps more common to use "countable" to mean "finite or countably infinite", so that, for example, every subset of a countable set is countable.)

Comment: Well, $\Bbb Z^+$ is countable, and so is $S$, by injectivity $v^{-1}(S)$ is countable, and then both $\Bbb Z^+\setminus  S$ and $\Bbb Z^+v^{-1}(S)$ are countable. Thus the intersection is countable.

Comment: The nonexistence of a fixed point makes no difference, and even if $v$ was not injecti ve this would still hold

Comment: it is indeed countably infinite, instead of finite.

Comment: Alright I came up with a counterexample. Let $v$ permutes all the integers pair-wisely i.e. $v\left ( 1 \right ) = 2, v\left ( 2 \right ) = 1; v\left ( 3 \right ) = 4, v\left ( 4 \right ) = 3 \ldots$. This is an injection obviously but if we take $S$ to be the odd number set then $v^{-1}\left ( S \right )$ is the even number set and hence has complement odd number set. But the complement of $S$ itself is the even number set. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counter example (I mentioned it in the comment)：

Define $v: \mathbb{Z^+} \leftrightarrow \mathbb{Z^+}$: $v\left(n\right) = n+1, \text{ for } n \text{ odd}; v\left(n\right) = n-1\text{ for } n \text{ even} $. Take $S$ to be the set of all odd numbers, then $\mathbb{Z^+}\setminus S$ is exactly the even number set. However, $v^{-1}\left(S\right)$ is the even number set by definition so it has complement odd number set. Now the contradiction is clear.